# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, keycloak

I am trying to use the `Keycloak` object to be able to create users directly from my Spring-Boot app.
I have the problem with `@Autowired`, when trying to deploy the application it gives me the error:

```
Field keycloak in UsersKCLKServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak' in your configuration.
```

How can I define a bean of this type in my config class? Isn't it enough to indicate in the .yaml the properties that I need?, like:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url: http://localhost:8081/auth
keycloak.realm: myRealm
keycloak.resource: myClient
keycloak.public-client: true
keycloak.credentials.secret: mySecret
```

This is my service class:

```
@Service
public class UsersKCLKServiceImpl implements UsersKCLKService{
        
    @Autowired
    private UsersKCLKRepository UsersKCLKRepository;
        
    @Autowired
    private Keycloak keycloak;

//... and my method which uses: 

    keycloak.realm("myRealm").users().create(myUser))
```

Comment: Did you add a dependency to `keycloak-spring-boot-starter`?

Comment: @Arie yes I did